# Excute scalar eror

Tags: c#, sql-server

**C#:**

```
  int lev;
            SqlCommand getlev = new SqlCommand("SELECT level FROM [User] WHERE Username = @username");
            getlev.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser.Text);
            c.Open();
            lev = (int)getlev.ExecuteScalar();
            c.Close();
            lev++;
            SqlCommand lvup= new SqlCommand("UPDATE [User] SET level = @lev WHERE Username = @username", c);
            lvup.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lev",lev);
            lvup.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser.Text);
            c.Open();
            lvup.ExecuteNonQuery();
            c.Close();
```

**Error:**

> ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteScalar:
>   Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: show the definition of `c`

Comment: The error message is self explanatory.  Set the Connection property on the getlev SqlCommand object.

Comment: You can add connection parameter to first `SqlCommand` like the Seconde, and you must not close connection if you want execute de seconde `SqlCommande`

Comment: Can do this atomically in one trip: `update [User] set lev += 1 output inserted.lev where Username = @username ` - returns the new lev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide the connection for the command. Use

```
getlev.Connection = c;
```

before executing `ExecuteScalar()`.

Or use the constructor overload that takes the connection:

```
SqlCommand getlev = new SqlCommand(
                            "SELECT level FROM [User] WHERE Username = @username",
                            c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a connection argument to the first SqlCommand:

```
SqlCommand getlev = new SqlCommand("SELECT level FROM [User] WHERE Username = @username", c);
```

You closed the connection before it is passed to the second SqlCommand:

```
c.Close(); // Remove this
lev++;
SqlCommand lvup= new SqlCommand("UPDATE [User] SET level = @lev WHERE Username = @username", c);
```